# on click event in setInterval function console.log double (sometimes triple) click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

First time asking a question, please bear with me. Thank you so much for your help!

My code is shown below. I am trying to create a Trivia Game.

My problem is that when I run the code, sometimes each click registers two or more click events. I did a bit of research and I think the explanation for this is because I am tying more than one event-listener to the same div area and it counts twice and thrice the more event-listeners attached to it. But I cannot figure out where and why this is happening.

```js
//  To set global variables and objects. 
var game = [
  [
    "How did Daenarys Targaryen eventually hatch her dragon eggs?", ["1. In a lightning storm", "2. In a funeral pyre", "3. In a fireplace", "4. In a frozen cave"],
    "2. In a funeral pyre",
    "assets/images/q1",
  ],
  [
    "The phrase 'Valar Morghulis' or 'all men must die' is usually responded with:", ["1. Valar Dohaeris or 'all men must serve'", "2. Valar Rohnas or 'all men must live'", "3. Valar GoGo or 'all men must dance'", "4. Valar Morghulis or 'all men must fight'"],
    "1. Valar Dohaeris or 'all men must serve'",
    "assets/images/q2",
  ],
  [
    "What is the only thing that can put out volatile Wildfire?", ["1. Sand", "2. Water", "3. Dragon's blood", "4. Sunlight"],
    "1. Sand",
    "assets/images/q3",
  ],
  [
    "Besides dragonglass, what is the only other substance capable of defeating White Walkers?", ["1. Weirwood", "2. Wildfire", "3. Valyrian Steel", "4. Magma"],
    "3. Valyrian Steel",
    "assets/images/q4",
  ],
  [
    "Arya's punishment for stealing from the Many-Face God is:", ["1. Death", "2. Memory Loss", "3. Blindness", "4. A Broken Arm"],
    "3. Blindness",
    "assets/images/q5",
  ],
  [
    "What was the name of Ned Stark's greatsword?", ["1. Oathkeeper", "2. Deathbringer", "3. Northguard", "4. Ice"],
    "4. Ice",
    "assets/images/q6",
  ],
  [
    "Who shoots the flaming arrow that subsequently destroy's Stannis' fleet in Blackwater Bay?", ["1. Tyrion Lannister", "2. King Joffrey", "3. Jaime Lannister", "4. Bronn"],
    "4. Bronn",
    "assets/images/q7",
  ],
  [
    "Prince Oberyn Martell is nicknamed the 'Red Viper' because of his combat and:", ["1. Pride in drawing blood first", "2. Knowledge of poisons", "3. Nighttime attacks", "4. Ruby-colored armor"],
    "2. Knowledge of poisons",
    "assets/images/q8",
  ],
  [
    "The Night King was created using a dagger made of:", ["1. Blue Ice", "2. Valyrian Steel", "3. Dragonglass", "4. Obsidian"],
    "3. Dragonglass",
    "assets/images/q9",
  ],
  [
    "How many arrows does Ramsay Bolton let loose at Rickon Stark?", ["1. Three", "2. Four", "3. Five", "4. Six"],
    "2. Four",
    "assets/images/q10",
  ],
]

var b = $.extend(true, [], game);
var qCountdown;
var ans;
var counter;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var correct = 0;
  var incorrect = 0;
  var unanswered = 0;
  var button = $(".optBtn");
  var start = $("#startBtn");
  var question = $("#question");
  var answer = $("#answer");
  var countdown = $("#timeout");
  var options;
  var qCounter = 0;

  // To hide certain HTML elements before the game starts.
  button.hide();

  // To Initiate the newGame function.
  function newGame() {
    nextQuestion();
  }

  // To initiate the nextQuestion function. 
  function nextQuestion() {
    countdown.show();
    question.show();
    button.show();
    start.hide();
    answer.empty();

    // Set the ending condition to display the results page. 
    if (qCounter !== 10) {
      test()
      // Set a condition and display for if the counter reaches 0.
      counter = 10;
      qCountdown = setInterval(function() {
        counter--;
        countdown.text(counter);
        if (counter === 0) {
          b.shift();
          clearInterval(qCountdown);
          countdown.hide();
          button.hide();
          console.log(qCounter + "TimeUp");
          console.log(b.length + "TimeUp");
          answer.text("The correct answer is " + ans + ".");
          $("#unanswered").text("Uh oh, you did not answer the question in time.");
          unanswered++;
          qCounter++;
          window.setTimeout(nextQuestion, 2000);
          return;
        }
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      b = $.extend(true, [], game);
      countdown.hide();
      question.hide();
      button.hide();
      start.show();
      clearInterval(qCountdown);
      answer.text("You guessed " + correct + " questions correctly, and " + incorrect + " questions incorrectly.");
      var unans = $("#unanswered");
      unans.text("You did not answer " + unanswered + " questions.");
      return;
    };
    var quest = question.text(b[0][0]);
    ans = b[0][2];
    var img;
    // console.log();

    // To assign each option button with one of the four options.
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      btns = {
        generator: function() {
          return b[0][1][i];
        }
      };

      button.each(function() {
        $(this).text(btns.generator());
        $(this).attr("data-value", btns.generator());
        i++;
      });
    }
  };

  function test() {
    // On-click function for the buttons to register a correct or incorrect guess. 
    button.on("click", function() {
      button.hide();
      console.log("You clicked a button once");

      options = $(this).attr("data-value");
      countdown.hide();
      question.hide();
      clearInterval(qCountdown);
      window.setTimeout(nextQuestion, 2000);
      qCounter++;
      b.shift();
      if (options === ans) {
        console.log(qCounter + "Click");
        console.log(b.length + "Click");
        answer.text("You guessed correctly, the answer is " + ans);
        correct++;
        button.off("click");
        return;
      } else {
        console.log(counter + "Clack");
        console.log(b.length + "Clack");
        answer.text("You guessed incorrectly, the answer is " + ans);
        incorrect++;
        button.off("click");
      };
    });

  }

  $("#startBtn").on("click", function() {

    // game = $.extend(true, [], b);
    newGame();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seeing your corresponding html would be helpful.

Comment: Also, you might consider using an array of objects instead of an array of arrays.

Comment: Every time you call `test()` inside `nextQuestion()`, you are creating a duplicate event binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that when time runs out you are calling `nextQuestion()` which calls `test()` which assigns `.on('click')` to every button of class `.optBtn`. However, you only turn the click event off if an answer is chosen.

So, if time runs out and no click is given, then a new click event is added to each button, thus you end up with multiple click events attached to your buttons.

Try moving the `button.off("click");` statements from their current location in your code, to a single call near the top of `nextQuestion()` or `test()`. So each time the timer runs out it will clear the click events, and attach it.

There may be better ways, and this is a long code snippet, but try that suggestion.